# How could an Android device lose its key for the SD-card?

Tags: sd-card, encryption

I am right now trying to debug a Lenovo P11 tablet that basically seems to have lost access to its SD card:

```
11-08 21:24:31.742   592   592 I vold    : Mounting emulated fuse volume
11-08 21:24:31.744   592   592 E vold    : Failed to create /mnt/expand/60dc08e3-0c91-4210-ac5f-88d6a4b4d65f/media/0/Android/: Required key not available
11-08 21:24:31.744   592   592 E vold    : Failed to prepare Android/ directories
```

This seems to cascade into several problems down the line:

```
11-08 21:24:41.268   592   592 E vold    : Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.gms/files/
11-08 21:24:46.141   592   592 E vold    : Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.docs/cache/
11-08 21:24:46.799   592   592 E vold    : Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.gms/files/
11-08 21:24:48.680   592   592 E vold    : Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.maps/files/
11-08 21:24:49.574   592   592 E vold    : Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.docs/cache/
11-08 21:24:59.244   592   592 E vold    : Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.gm/cache/
11-08 21:25:07.889   592   592 E vold    : Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.gms/cache/
11-08 21:25:13.926   592   592 E vold    : Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/files/
11-08 21:25:14.060   592   592 E vold    : Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/cache/
```

I am not an Android expert and my Linux expertise only carries so far here. But it seems to me that the SD Card was mounted successfully but then a process called "vold" tried to unlock the Android folder with fscrypt because it could not find the key. In turn, several apps fail to read/write their internal storage which was mapped onto the SD card.

Am I right so far?

If I am right, I have to wonder: How does Android identify the key to a folder? Could the device really lose the key (after mere weeks of working just fine)? Could that be the consequence of a recent system upgrade (Android 10 to 11, I think)?

Final question: Is there any chance, whatsoever, to retrieve the key (even with rooting the device)?

Comment: usually adoptable-storage uses [dm-crypt](https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html) (but I might be wrong) Where did you see fscrypt? on locked bootloader your only chance is exploit to access /data/misc/vold (like mtk-su). I doubt there is any method to recover data after encryption key is lost